# How can I make Google include special characters to search for programming terms?

Tags: google-search

This comes up from time to time when I want to search for a line of code, and it's perhaps something common to many languages or is a word/phrase outside of programming.  The special characters and formatting are what makes my query unique.  However, Google ignores almost all special characters.  I have put my string in quotes and also used verbatim mode.  No dice.  If I search "/echo/html/" (including the quotation marks), even in verbatim mode, Google finds results such as "You need to echo HTML" which do not include my forward slashes.  I've read [this Help article from Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1734130?hl=en&ref_topic=3081620) but it doesn't address my situation.  The same problem exists for `<>`, `()`, and many other common programming special characters.  If I want to read about `<head>` or `print()`, I need to include words like "HTML" or "Python" and even then I might get hits that aren't about the specific query I want.  `.` seems to be included, so searching for `.Net` is not a problem.

Is there a solution I'm missing?  Am I just not able to use the search how I would like?

Comment: This has been answered here on Stack Overflow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685615/search-engine-for-special-characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com), it's a search engine that allows you to search with special chars. This allowed me to search for very specific functions/errors rather than the special chars being replaced with spaces and bringing up irrelevant stuff.