# Exclude ".NET" from a Google search for "Microsoft Net Server"

Tags: google-search

I'm trying to do some research on a product that I believe may have existed quite some time ago called *Microsoft Net Server* (cf. [this article](http://windowsitpro.com/networking/why-cant-i-map-drive-its-ip-address) from 2000) which was apparently some sort of file server service. However, despite my fanciest handstands while gargling peanut butter, the only thing Google gives me are results related to Microsoft's .NET Framework.

I've tried:

- `Microsoft Net Server`
- `"Microsoft Net Server"`
- `Microsoft "Net Server"`
- `Microsoft "Net Server" -".NET" -"DOT"`
- `Microsoft +"Net Server"`
- `gimme teh kodez for Microsoft Net Server`

I also went to Google's [Advanced Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search) and plugged my query the best I knew how. No dice. Then I found this WebApps [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/55009/163653) which lead me to http://symbolhound.com where I did an advanced search excluding the terms `.net` and `dot` and got back a whopping two results, neither of which were the sample article I referenced above.

**How can I search for `Net` and exclude results that contain `.Net`?**

Comment: The only way that I've been able to find the article you referenced is by including `1.11` in the results `"microsoft net server 1.11"`: https://goo.gl/WfrPxX but I get 0 results when searching for the exact phrase `Microsoft Net Server` on Symbol Hound: http://symbolhound.com/?q=&l=&e=Microsoft+Net+Server&n=&u= I'm sure this isn't helpful, but I feel your pain. :)

Answer (score -3):

"Microsoft Net Server 1.11" -"."net

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work either!

Comment: Read Discontinued server products from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Servers